# OnClick event not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have these 3 divs:

```
<div id="home_type">2 Storey</div>
<div id="home_type">Bungalow/ Bungalow Loft</div>
<div id="home_type">Townhome</div>
```

and I have this onclick event:

```
$('#home_type').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

but it only works for the first item, here is my jfiddle (which also doesn't work, throwing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`)

http://jsfiddle.net/o1arL1q7/1/

When I click on an item on my site, I get no errors and I only get the alert for the first item. How can I fix this?

Comment: ID's **must** be unique! Use a *class* for common elements.

Comment: About the JSFIDDLE, you got to set jQuery on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/o1arL1q7/3/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the id attribute must be unique. Try this (replacing id for a class):

**HTML**

```
<div class="home_type">2 Storey</div>
<div class="home_type">Bungalow/ Bungalow Loft</div>
<div class="home_type">Townhome</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.home_type').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

*The error thrown by jsFidle is because is missing a jQuery reference. You can include it in the **Framework & Extensions** menu.

Answer (score 3):

`ID`'s must be unique. The problem is you are trying to use the same ID multiple times so only the first found will work. Use a class instead.

```
<div class="home_type">2 Storey</div>
<div class="home_type">Bungalow/ Bungalow Loft</div>
<div class="home_type">Townhome</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.home_type').click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements in the DOM with the same ID. You would need to make those classes or change their ID's

**HTML**

```
<div class="home_type">2 Storey</div>
<div class="home_type">Bungalow/ Bungalow Loft</div>
<div class="home_type">Townhome</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.home_type').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o1arL1q7/4/